# Update MS Access field to NOW when another field changes for current record

Tags: sql, ms-access, expression, calculated-columns

Question: I am trying to update a field in an MS Access database when another field changes, but it should only update the field of the current record I am changing.

I have tried to use the calculated fields with expressions, but have had no luck.

[image: current DB]

Please let me know if this is possible!

Comment: If you are working with Access 2010 or later you could use a Before Change data macro on the table to achieve that result.

Comment: Create CRUD stored procs, ensure the update proc maintains the timestamp column as required, etc.

Comment: try the IIF statement instead of IFF